# Writing HttpService on JBoss

Tags: http, jboss, apache-camel, httpservice

I have written http client using camel http connector. Currently JBoss is chosen as my application server. I would like to write a HttpService that should run on JBoss which can receive and process the payload from client.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a REST service running on the Jboss server which can be easily built using jersey or resteasy frameworks. Other REST libraries can be used too.

The http service can be built using the plain servlet too. But REST libraries provide a lot of builtin support.

Comment: How about EJB/DAO which is exposed via JNDI? The client access the service using JNDI. Problem uncovered is whether JNDI supports streaming data, means posting reasonable size of content.

Comment: You said you wanted to build an HTTP Service?

Comment: Ideally HTTP Service is what I thought a standard way. Earlier I have used JNDI for authentication but not for posting content to a HttpService way. Wanted to clear my doubt. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I am sorry. But i dont see why you need JNDI to post to the HttpServcie. If you are using camel it will take care of posting to the http url.